# The blkid PTTYPE of dos

Tags: linux, partitioning

What does the `blkid` output of `PTTYPE` of "`dos`" actually mean?

This is the `blkid` output of `ext4` partition that I used to see:

```
$ blkid /dev/sdc7
/dev/sdc7: LABEL="lbr7" UUID="2278..." TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="44c4...-07"
```

However, today I noticed that another disk is output like this:

```
$ blkid /dev/sdc6
/dev/sdc6: LABEL="lbr6" UUID="a7db..." TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="44c4...-06"
```

Why `PTTYPE` of "`dos`" for an `ext4` partition?

The only place `PTTYPE` is mentioned in `blkid` man page is:

> ...information about partition table type  (PTTYPE  tag)...

Answer (score 3):

PTTYPE is the type of the partition table that the partition was recognized from. The only values you're likely to see for this property are "dos" for devices using MBR partitioning, and "gpt" for devices using GPT. (Or possibly "apm" for some older Macintosh hard disks, although you're unlikely to run into many of those.)

Comment: Well, that make it more interesting as my `sdc6` and `sdc7` are from the _exact same_ disk. I.e., both of them should have the same partition table, either MBR or GPT, but their PTTYPE are different. In fact, I did `blkid | grep 'sdc.*ext'` and found that only `sdc6` has that PTTYPE entry, the rest of ~10 partitions, none of them have it.

Comment: @xpt: I get the `PTTYPE` output only for the whole drive device, e.g. `/dev/sdc` but not for partitions.

Comment: @mpy, I bet, which makes it really confusing. I checked again, and found several other PTTYPE="dos" entries, all at partition level, and all are ext2/3/4 types. All my partition tables were created by `gparted`. What about yours?